# Problems using glmulti package in RStudio to predict best model

Tags: r, model, glmulti

So I am trying to use the "glmulti" package find the best combination of variables (or best model) for my response variable Bio_class. Bio_class is a categorical variable that contains 5 outcomes (4 species and 1 absence option). I have 56 numerical variables (temperature, salinity, chlorophyll, etc.) that I am trying to test in the model. I have followed other posts online for how to use the package but I am getting errors. I am fairly new to R so any recommendations on whether to include random effects or not would be appreciated. Please let me know if you have any questions. I know this is ALOT of data to put into the package but I hope it works. Ive also with less variables and excluded substrate and I get a different error.

Many thanks

```
library(glmulti)
library(metafor)

data.na<- na.omit(alldata) #remove any rows with NAs in them
anyNA(data.na) #FALSE = no NAs in dataset

rma.glmulti <- function(formula, data, ...)
rma(formula, vi, data=data, method="ML", ...) #defining the function 'rma.glmulti'

res <- glmulti(
    Bio_class~Temp_winter+Temp_spring+Temp_summer+Temp_autumn+Temp_yr_avg
    +Temp_yr_max+Temp_yr_min+Sal_winter+Sal_spring+Sal_summer+Sal_autumn
    +Sal_yr_avg+Sal_yr_max+Sal_yr_min+Chl_winter+Chl_spring+Chl_summer+Chl_autumn
    +Chl_yr_avg+Chl_yr_max+Chl_yr_min+Nit_winter+Nit_spring+Nit_summer+Nit_autumn
    +Nit_yr_avg+Nit_yr_max+Nit_yr_min+ZSD_winter+ZSD_spring+ZSD_summer+ZSD_autumn
    +ZSD_yr_avg+ZSD_yr_max+ZSD_yr_min+Phos_winter+Phos_spring+Phos_summer          
    +Phos_autumn+Phos_yr_avg+Phos_yr_max+Phos_yr_min+SWH_winter+SWH_spring
    +SWH_summer+SWH_autumn+SWH_yr_avg+SWH_yr_max+SWH_yr_min+Depth
    +Dist_to_major_cities+Dist_to_complete_cities+Dist_to_port
    +Dist_to_major_river+Dist_to_complete_river+Dist_to_coast, 
    data=data.na,
    level=1,
    fitfunction=rma.glmulti, 
    crit="aicc", 
    confsetsize=7.2057594e+16
)

print(res)
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not in attached pictures

Comment: I would but I am a new member and it the website wouldn't let me Im sorry

Comment: Hi @SGilk, what Slava meant is, please type copy and paste your code as text. The image is essentially useless for reproducing your error. You can place your code in a code indent using one of the "bars"

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev , I added the code below now. Also I want to be clear, Bioclass is my response variable and I have 56 numerical variables. I want to use this package to determine the best model predictor for bio_class. I know in the picture it shows a category labelled "substrate." please ignore it as I have omitted it.

Comment: @StupidWolf Please see my updated post with code

Comment: Error in vi == 0 : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types . I followed instructions online and can't seem to figure out how to use vi or what it is.

Comment: what's  the error? and my suggestion to try it on an example dataset, see that you don't get any error then run it on your dataset

Comment: Error in vi == 0 : comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: You can see my error in the comment above. also I have tried using different variables and a much smaller version of the dataset and still having the same error

Comment: You seem to have gotten code from [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:model_selection_with_glmulti_and_mumin). But why are you using `rma()` to fit your models? Are you even conducting a meta-analysis? Based on your description of `Bio_class`, it doesn't sound like it. Sounds more to me like you would want to fit multinomial regression models. Also, you are trying to fit 7.21^16 different models. You will have to wait until the end of the universe for this to finish.